# changing CCNode position does not affect children

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to move my CCNode which has CCSprite in it and it does not work. 
I subbclassed from CCNode and try to move that object
here's how I add sprite to node in my init method:

```
_sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"shroom.png"];
[self addChild:_sprite];
[self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_sprite.boundingBox.size.width, _sprite.boundingBox.size.height)];
```

and when I drag that object I call

```
-(void) moveTo:(CGPoint)pt
{
     [self setPosition:pt];
}
```

NSLog says that node's position is changed but my sprite (which is child of this node) stays still.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where do you set the position of the sprite inside the CCNode class?

Comment: inside of CCNode subclass I change self.position, hence I change the position of the node itself. And I was expecting that the position of the sprite will also change.

Comment: So is your moveTo method in your CCNode subclass?  You should be setting the position on the screen in your scene.m methods.

Comment: change position of the whole scene just to make a single picture move? It's easier for me to change the position of the sprite within the node. But why changing the position of the node does not change the position of its children? That's the question

Comment: But the CCNode should be a child of your scene.  You have to remember that an object class is really a factory that can produce multiple objects.  You allocate it in your scene by MyObject=[[MyClass alloc] init].  Then you add it as a child to your scene and set the position.  Maybe I'm not totally following what your issue is, but it sounds like you are trying to move a sprite around the screen using your subclass.  This isn't quite right because the CCNode's position on the screen is defined by your scene.